# Why is DefaultLoggerContext returned after initiliazing the log42.xml?

Tags: log4j2

I have been getting this error once the server is started and the error says that the log4j2.xml is not found,

```
[11/17/16 11:36:04:007 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemErr     R ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Below is the log4j2.xml that is configured.

```
<Configuration status="trace" name="ICM_App" packages="scb.framework.logger.service.util"
  monitorInterval="1800">
  <Appenders>
    <Routing name="common_ref">
      <Routes pattern="$${file:fileName}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${file:fileName}"
            fileName="${file:fileName}.log" filePattern="${file:fileName}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>[%d{dd/MM/yyyy#HH:mm:ss:S}] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" fileIndex="max" min="1" compressionLevel="5"/>
            <Policies>
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
            </Policies>
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>

    <Routing name="Integration_ref">
      <Routes pattern="$${file:fileName}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${file:fileName}"
            fileName="${file:fileName}.log" filePattern="${file:fileName}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>[%d{dd/MM/yyyy#HH:mm:ss:S}] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" fileIndex="max" min="1" compressionLevel="5"/>
            <Policies>
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
            </Policies>
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
<Console name="STDOUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd/MM/yyyy#HH:mm:ss:S}] %m%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>


  <!-- Define the Loggers including Root, Inside program this name will be called -->
  <Loggers>

  <!-- Root Logger to write log into console, in the worst case scenario if some think went wrong -->
     <Root level="error">
     <AppenderRef ref="common_ref"/>
     </Root>

  <!-- Default Logger Setup - Log will be written based on the input request, file name will be determined by system -->
    <AsyncLogger name="common" level="ALL" additivity="FALSE" includeLocation="true" >
      <AppenderRef ref="common_ref" />
    </AsyncLogger>

  <!-- User Specific log setup, like request.log, listner.log etc -->
    <AsyncLogger name="Integration" level="ALL" additivity="FALSE" includeLocation="true" >
      <AppenderRef ref="Integration_ref" />
    </AsyncLogger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

So , i changed the level to trace in the log4j2.xml and got the below logs in the console.

```
[11/17/16 11:36:08:885 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,884 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/apps/config/log4j2.xml]
[11/17/16 11:36:08:886 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,886 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Installed script engines
[11/17/16 11:36:08:976 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,976 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Mozilla Rhino Version: 1.7 release 3 PRERELEASE, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: MULTITHREADED, Compile: true, Names: {js, rhino, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
[11/17/16 11:36:08:980 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,979 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Took 0.001964 seconds to load 0 plugins from package scb.framework.logger.service.util
[11/17/16 11:36:08:980 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,980 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 97 plugins
[11/17/16 11:36:08:981 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,981 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
[11/17/16 11:36:08:988 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,987 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Starting 1 Log4j2Scheduled threads
[11/17/16 11:36:08:990 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,989 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 14 plugins
[11/17/16 11:36:08:994 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:08,993 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Route, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.Route].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:014 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,014 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:015 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,015 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
[11/17/16 11:36:09:028 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,028 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createRoute(ref="null", key="null", Node=Route)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:029 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,029 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Routes, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.Routes].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:035 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,035 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createRoutes(pattern="${file:fileName}", ={Route(type=dynamic - type=Route default)})
[11/17/16 11:36:09:036 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,036 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:042 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,041 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createAppender(name="common_ref", ignoreExceptions="null", Routes({Route(type=dynamic - type=Route default)}), Configuration(ICM_App), RewritePolicy=null, PurgePolicy=null, Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:043 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,043 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Route, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.Route].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:045 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,044 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createRoute(ref="null", key="null", Node=Route)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:045 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,045 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Routes, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.Routes].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:046 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,046 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createRoutes(pattern="${file:fileName}", ={Route(type=dynamic - type=Route default)})
[11/17/16 11:36:09:047 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,047 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.routing.RoutingAppender].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:049 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,048 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createAppender(name="Integration_ref", ignoreExceptions="null", Routes({Route(type=dynamic - type=Route default)}), Configuration(ICM_App), RewritePolicy=null, PurgePolicy=null, Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:050 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,049 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:058 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,058 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="[%d{dd/MM/yyyy#HH:mm:ss:S}] %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(ICM_App), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
[11/17/16 11:36:09:060 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,059 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
[11/17/16 11:36:09:095 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,094 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:100 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,100 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:101 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,101 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 38 plugins
[11/17/16 11:36:09:103 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,102 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-4
[11/17/16 11:36:09:112 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,111 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(PatternLayout([%d{dd/MM/yyyy#HH:mm:ss:S}] %m%n), Filter=null, target="null", name="STDOUT", follow="null", ignoreExceptions="null")
[11/17/16 11:36:09:113 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,112 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false
[11/17/16 11:36:09:113 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,113 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:115 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,115 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createAppenders(={common_ref, Integration_ref, STDOUT})
[11/17/16 11:36:09:116 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,116 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:117 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,117 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="common_ref", level="null", Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:118 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,118 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:120 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,120 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ERROR", includeLocation="null", ={common_ref}, ={}, Configuration(ICM_App), Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:125 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,125 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:126 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,126 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="common_ref", level="null", Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:127 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,127 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=asyncLogger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:130 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,130 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="FALSE", level="ALL", name="common", includeLocation="true", ={common_ref}, ={}, Configuration(ICM_App), Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:138 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,138 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:139 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,139 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="Integration_ref", level="null", Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:140 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,140 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=asyncLogger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:142 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,141 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="FALSE", level="ALL", name="Integration", includeLocation="true", ={Integration_ref}, ={}, Configuration(ICM_App), Filter=null)
[11/17/16 11:36:09:142 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,142 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
[11/17/16 11:36:09:144 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,144 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG createLoggers(={root, common, Integration})
[11/17/16 11:36:09:145 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,145 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/apps/config/log4j2.xml] initialized
[11/17/16 11:36:09:146 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,146 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/apps/config/log4j2.xml]
[11/17/16 11:36:09:149 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,149 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE AsyncLoggerConfigHelper creating new disruptor for this configuration.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:279 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,279 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Starting AsyncLoggerConfig disruptor for this configuration with ringbufferSize=262144, waitStrategy=BlockingWaitStrategy, exceptionHandler=null...
[11/17/16 11:36:09:282 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,282 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[common] starting...
[11/17/16 11:36:09:283 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,283 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE AsyncLoggerConfig[Integration] starting...
[11/17/16 11:36:09:284 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,284 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/apps/config/log4j2.xml] OK.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:285 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,284 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3c3d5fdd...
[11/17/16 11:36:09:285 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,285 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:286 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,286 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:287 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,287 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:288 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,287 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:288 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,288 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false-3
[11/17/16 11:36:09:289 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,289 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:290 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,290 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:291 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,290 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@3c3d5fdd OK
[11/17/16 11:36:09:291 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,291 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@4bc79692
[11/17/16 11:36:09:292 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,292 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): 'c0ae655e' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6b032e73
[11/17/16 11:36:09:293 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,293 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e]
[11/17/16 11:36:09:294 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,294 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=StatusLogger]
[11/17/16 11:36:09:295 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,295 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=ContextSelector]
[11/17/16 11:36:09:296 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,296 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=Loggers,name=*'
[11/17/16 11:36:09:297 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,297 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2]
[11/17/16 11:36:09:298 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,298 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
[11/17/16 11:36:09:299 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,299 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
[11/17/16 11:36:09:300 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,300 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
[11/17/16 11:36:09:301 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,301 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e
[11/17/16 11:36:09:302 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,302 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=StatusLogger
[11/17/16 11:36:09:303 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,303 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=ContextSelector
[11/17/16 11:36:09:304 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,304 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c0ae655e,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2
[11/17/16 11:36:09:305 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,305 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:306 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,305 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=Default] at URI /apps/config/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@ed745992) with optional ClassLoader: null
[11/17/16 11:36:09:306 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,306 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
[11/17/16 11:36:09:307 GMT+00:00] 0000008e SystemOut     O 2016-11-17 14:36:09,307 WebSphere_EJB_Timer_Service_WorkManager.Alarm Pool : 0 DEBUG LoggerContext[name=Default, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@ed745992] started OK
```

Ours is an EJB application with multiple EJBs and WAR files.
The log4j2.xml resides in the custom config path and it is read by setting the below property in the code

System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "/apps/config/log4j2.xml")

Both EJB and WEB App throw the same error. Below are the jars available in the shared library path in following order..

```
 log4j-api-2.5.jar
 log4j-core-2.5.jar 
 log4j-2.0.jar
 slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
```

Would appreciate if someone could hint on why the Default configuration is returned after initiliazing, just started implementing the log4j2 in our project.. so any leads would be helpful... thank you...

**Update**

Have done the changes that is being recommended and then it was still not working. Our application uses hibernate 4.2.7 and hence the following jar was available in the library - jboss-logging-3.2.0.Final.jar. Once i remove it, the logwriter was working fine. But when we have any call to DAO which uses the hibernate session, we get this

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.BasicLogger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243
```

So, trying to figure out the right version of the jboss-logging jar for the log4j2.5 !!

**Final Update**

Added the jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar to the shared library and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring logging for a web or EJB application, a lot depends on the structure of your application, where the log4j2 jars are located and where the configuration file is located. EDIT: thanks for updating your question with some more detail.

I see this notification in the Log4j status messages your posted, you may want to add the log4j-web jar to your dependencies:

> INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's
>   no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container
>   support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server
>   lib directory.

Looking at the dependencies, I'm assuming you're on Java 6 and that is why you're using an older version of Log4j2. (If not, please upgrade to the latest, currently 2.7).

Please remove

```
log4j-2.0.jar //what's this?
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar // Log4j 1.2
```

Instead, add

```
log4j-web-2.5.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar
```

I see you have a custom `file:` lookup that is used as the Routing key as well as the file name. Does the problem also occur if you don't use the custom lookup?

Comment: Have edited the question to add the info that is requested for.I have already tried adding the log4j-web JAR to the classpath library.but still it is not working.Reg the Lookups,Yes,we have written a custom file: as below

Comment: @Plugin(name="file", category="Lookup")
public class FileLookup
  implements StrLookup
{
  public String lookup(String key)
  {
    return Thread.currentThread().getName();
  }
  public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key)
  {
    return ThreadContext.getFileName(event.getThreadID() + event.getLoggerName());
  }

Comment: Please add more detail: Where are the Log4j jars located? Which application is reporting the "No log4j2 configuration file found" error? The EJB or the web app WAR or both? Is the error message correct: do you actually only see info-level console logging or are some (which?) applications able to log to the files?

Comment: Also, does the same error occur if you have a simpler configuration, for example with a single File appender?

Comment: Updated the answer. You can also file a JIRA on the Log4j2 issue tracker to ask the whole community.

Comment: I will do the changes mentioned and then test... Would raise a JIRA on the log4j2 issue tracker if still not able to solve / crack the issue.   thanks a ton for ur inputs.